# derivative of $\sqrt{kx}$

Tags: derivatives

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+k^%281%2F2%29*x^%281%2F2%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20k%5E%281%2F2%29*x%5E%281%2F2%29)

Here's my shot at it:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{kx} = (kx)^\frac{1}{2}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(kx)^\frac{-1}{2}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{kx}$$

What's wrong with my answer, and how do I get to the correct answer? Wolframalpha's answer is different:

$$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: write it as $f(x)=k^{1/2}x^{1/2}$, $k ^{1/2}$ is just a constant $f'(x)=k^{1/2}*(x^{1/2})'=k ^{1/2}*\frac{1}{2*x^{1/2}}$ which is wolfram alpha answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the second line: $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(kx)^\frac{-1}{2}$.

$f(x)$ is a function of $x$, but you apply the derivative on $kx$ instead.

It might make it easier for you to differentiate $f(x)=\sqrt{k}\cdot\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: why is k treated as a constant? What if the exponent of $k$ and $x$ are different? How do you know which variable is the constant?

Comment: @user1534664: Because you are differentiating by variable $x$.

Comment: Arent I differentiating $\sqrt{kx}$ rather than $x$? I don't understand why you only choose to use the power rule only on 1 variable.

Comment: @user1534664: $f(x)$ is a function of $x$. If it was a function of **both** $k$ and $x$, then you would need to decide what partial derivative you want calculate (i.e., either by $k$ or by $x$), and then treat the other variable as a constant for that matter (the "partial derivative" matter).

Comment: Ahhh, I never knew that. So, basically all variables are constants except the variables inside $f(...)$? Is this the case for all scenario's?

Comment: @user1534664: $f(x)$ is not a function of $k$, so yes - $k$ is constant as far as "$f$ is concerned".

Comment: Thank you, I would've never thought I misunderstood functions... Though, the assignment never said $f(x)$, it just said, find the derivative of $\sqrt{kx}$. Do you just assume that $k$ is a constant because it's the letter $k$ rather than $y$ for example?

Comment: @user1534664: Well, that's what most people would do (if it's just a simple assignment in a basic course that you're taking or whatever). But in general, the assignment should specify what is the variable of the function. And if it's a multi-variable function, then the assignment should also specify which partial derivative should be calculated (i.e., by which variable the function should be differentiated). And of course, all other variables are treated as constant for the partial-differentiating operation.

Comment: @user1534664 No! Not all variables others than what's inside $f(...)$ are treated as constants. Btw In your question it must have stated that k is a constant, and normally k is referred to as a constant by convention (as long as it's not specified that it depends on x) . Also, if it was $f(x)=\sqrt{yx}$ , then even if it's no stated in the question that y is a constant, by convention we normally treat y as a dependant variable on x, so  the method would work (you have to use the chain rule). Normally when it comes to exercises, $c$ and $k$ are used for constants, whereas $x,y,z$ for variables.

Comment: @TheArtist So basically I can never be sure that a variable is a constant unless it's specified? It actually made alot of sense if the variables not inside $f(...)$ were constants, since it's a nice convention. Can you give me a scenario where this is not the case (without going high level math)?

Comment: @TheArtist "Also if it was $f(x) = \sqrt{yx}$..." You've got me confused here. Do you mean any variable in front of x is treated as a constant by default unless specified otherwise? It's weird dealing with side cases like that since $f(x) = y$ in general.

Comment: My real question here is: How can I tell whether a variable is a constant or not?

Comment: @user1534664 It doesn't make sense to everything outside $f(...)$ to be constants always. You seem to be obsessed with your primary education that y is f(x), there is no such rule (unless stated). As you asked for an example, let me stay away from using y, since you seemed to be confused, take (z is not a constant) $f(x)=xz \implies f'(x)=x \frac{dz}{dx}+ z \cdot 1$

Comment: @user1534664 Please confirm whether you mean "How can I tell whether a variable used in my course is a constant or not?" Or "How can I tell whether a variable is a constant or not?"

Comment: @TheArtist Both :D

Comment: @user1534664 How can I tell whether a variable used in my course is a constant or not if its not mentioned in the question which is what ? Ask your teacher/lecturer what are the letters used in the course which assumes its a constant and variable. Like I said most schools , when I was in high school we use k and c for constant, whereas x,y,z are variables and when other letters are used they mention it! Check your syllabus, or ask your teacher.

Comment: @TheArtist Ah okay. Thanks. So it's context dependent. I think you're right, I'm very used to treating $y$ as $f(x)$...  Thats why I find your example very confusing. I don't understand what $\frac{dz}{dx}$ is. In course assignments I generally see $\frac{dy}{dx}$ which just means $f'(x)$. I'd like to ask you another question in my next comment:

Comment: @TheArtist from my point of view, there's generally two types of variables: the ones that change, and the ones that don't (constants). In your example, if $z$ is not a constant but a variable, then don't we have to give a value to the variable through $f(x, z)$...? E.g. if we have $f(x)$ you could say $f(9)$, so we want the value of $f$ when $x = 9$. Sorry if it seems blatantly obvious to you, I've only been into math for ~20 weeks...

Comment: @user1534664 If $f(x)=xz$, so $f(9)=9z$ , they can tell how z depends on x, for example: $z=9x^2$ , so $z=9(9^2)=9^3$ , thus $f(9)=9z=9(9^3)=9^4$.

Comment: @TheArtist Thank you. After your comment and doing some research I understand it now :)

Comment: @user1534664 also your point of view is wrong. "There are two types of variables, one that changes and ones which are constant" . Wrong! Errr....There are no such two, variable by definition varies (changes) . Constants aren't variables. "variable" is not a category of the two, Variables and constants are two very different things.

Comment: @TheArtist Ah ok. I thought letters were variables and therefore constants were variables. But, now I understand that constants and variables are both letters, but they are different things.

Comment: @user1534664 Google's definition: Variable - not consistent or having a fixed pattern; liable to change.

Comment: @user1534664 time for you to change your thoughts. Anyways, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use the chain rule: $$f'(x) = \frac 12(kx)^{-1/2}\cdot \frac {d}{dx}(kx) =\frac 12 \cdot \frac 1{\sqrt {kx}} \cdot k = \frac {k}{2\sqrt{k}\sqrt x} = \frac{\sqrt k}{2\sqrt x}= \frac 12\sqrt{\frac kx}$$

Without the chain rule, you have $$f(x) = \sqrt {kx} = \sqrt k \cdot \sqrt x$$ Note that $\sqrt k$ is a constant (we must treat it as such since we are differentiating with respect to $x$,  And for any constant $c$, $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(cf(x)\Big) = cf'(x)$$

So $$f'(x) = \sqrt k \cdot \frac 12 (x)^{-1/2} = \frac{\sqrt k}{2\sqrt x} = \frac 12\sqrt{\frac kx}$$

Comment: I'm not using the chain rule yet. It's possible without it according to khanacademy.

Answer (score 0):

- Factor out the constants. (everything except x)
- Use standard formula $\frac{{\rm d}x^n}{{\rm d}x}=nx^{n-1}$
  $$\frac{{\rm d}\sqrt{kx}}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{{\rm d}(\sqrt{k}.\sqrt x)}{{\rm d}x}=\sqrt k\frac{{\rm d}x^{1/2}}{{\rm d}x}=\sqrt{k}\frac12x^{1/2-1}=\frac{\sqrt k}{2\sqrt x}=\frac12\sqrt{\frac kx}$$